# Row having more white space at top and bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having problem with the bootstrap rows, where I am getting more white space at top and bottom of the rows, which I need to remove, I want the row to have just the height of the text present inside it...

HTML is given below :

```
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-muted">
            <p>Author</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-right font-bold">
            <p>abcd</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row row-divider"></div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-muted">
            <p>Date Created</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-right font-bold">
            <p>Nov 28, 19:30</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row row-divider"></div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-muted">
            <p>File Type</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-right font-bold">
            <p>Microsoft Word</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row row-divider"></div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-muted">
            <p>Last Modified</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6  text-right font-bold">
          <p>Dec 08, 11:00</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: hope your code is working fine.. http://jsfiddle.net/RxguB/83/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set:

```
p{
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 14px; /*you can reduce this value to achieve what you want*/
}
```

[Here a JSFiddle example to play with](https://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/uk8buddL/)

Note that `.row-divider` has `margin: 9px 0px` if you want you can reduce it to closer to the text above it.

Check this out for more information about `line-height` http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp

Comment: I think this works for me.. setting the line-height to the lowest possible value in my case. thanks

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is add the following CSS to your code:

```
.row-divider {
  height: 1px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e7eaec;
}
p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1;
}
```

You basically tell all your paragraphs to have 0 margins so the line height is equal to the text height.

On a different note, you might want to use `text-muted` class on the `<p>` tags instead of the whole `<div>` that contains those `<p>` tags. Why? because for example tomorrow you will add two more lines to that div that wouldn't need to be `text-muted`, you would need to define a new class to cancel those values.
**Style the things you need and only those**.

If you want the left text and right text on the same line in Jsfiddle just change the `col-sm-x` class to `col-xs-x` class, basically, jsfiddle view is a bit small and that's why you see two lines.

Comment: This is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/bharos92/whpmr5r6/
Even after  the changes for adding margin and padding as 0,
you can see that row is still having white space above and below...
Can it be minimized..?
And yes, it can be seen in two lines in fiddle, but it is in one line only in my page , may be because of the reason you suggested..But in the fiddle , please note that it still has more white space at top and bottom

Comment: Please see this : https://jsfiddle.net/b2gfnc94/ 
Basically, my doubt is can I have the row-divider even closer to the text above it

Comment: I have revised my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
p{
    margin: 5px 0px;

}
.clearfix {
    zoom: 1;
}

    .clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        line-height: 0;
    }

    .clearfix:after {
        clear: both;
    }
```

use clearfix class with row.

Comment: I am not able to get the space reduced with the clearfix class suggested